# Is request Content-Type header optional?

Tags: http

Is Content-Type header optional for multipart/form-data requests? I mean each Content-Disposition section. Please refer to RFCs in your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RFC 2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt), from *3. Definition of multipart/form-data*:

> As with all multipart MIME types, each part has an **optional**
>    "Content-Type", which defaults to text/plain.  If the contents of a
>    file are returned via filling out a form, then the file input is
>    identified as the appropriate media type, if known, or
>    "application/octet-stream".  If multiple files are to be returned as
>    the result of a single form entry, they should be represented as a
>    "multipart/mixed" part embedded within the "multipart/form-data".